# External IP Port is not open for Hadoop Port 9000

Tags: hadoop, port, firewall

Take note of the port 9000 below. It's open for localhost but not the external IP. Anyone can provide help? I have already disabled the firewall

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-29 05:53 PDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000020s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
23/tcp   open  telnet
25/tcp   open  smtp
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
8031/tcp open  unknown
8042/tcp open  fs-agent
8088/tcp open  radan-http
9000/tcp open  cslistener

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.51 seconds
[root@localhost ~]# nmap 192.168.146.128

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-29 05:54 PDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.146.128
Host is up (0.000037s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
23/tcp   open  telnet
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
8031/tcp open  unknown
8042/tcp open  fs-agent
8088/tcp open  radan-http


[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=9000/tcp
```

FirewallD is not running

Comment: Not sure how this is a Hadoop question. What service are you expecting to be on that port? HDFS? Did you you set fs.defaultFS only to localhost:9000? What is `cslistener`?

Answer (score 1):

Modify core-site.xml. For the entry `fs.default.name`, change the value to `hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000` and restart the service.

If you set the entry to localhost, then TCP will listen on 127.0.0.1 which is only available internally to the machine. Using 0.0.0.0 means listen on all network interfaces which allows for external access.